# Switch Case statement or its alternate If Condition is not working in android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, switch-statement

I as using switch case for a condition check. It is not working. Here how I have implemented.

```
@Override
public void onReceiveNotification(String notificationType, String message, String flag) {
    super.onReceiveNotification(notificationType, message, flag);
    Log.d("tag", "==onReceive Notivation====1===" + notificationType);
    if (notificationType.equalsIgnoreCase("MULTIPART_TYPES"))
    {
        Log.d("tag", "==onReceive Notivation===2====" + notificationType);
    }
    switch (notificationType) {
        case "MULTIPART_TYPES":
            Log.d("tag", "==onReceive Notivation=======" + message);
            break;
    }
}
```

this is my Log output

> ==onReceive Notivation====1=== MULTIPART_TYPES

However it is entering into the method with respected string message. But it is not entering to the either to switch or if conditions.

Comment: Could you add your log output.

Comment: @jbarat, I have added log out . Pls check

Comment: put the else condition in if block and default in switch. and check if its entering on else or default block or not.

Comment: There is a leading soace. Look harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space front of your notificationType. 
Remove it or add trimming to your check. Something like this.

```
if (notificationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("MULTIPART_TYPES"))
    {
        Log.d("tag", "==onReceive Notivation===2====" + notificationType);
    }
```